# How to get results from celery tasks from another app in another host

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using django, celery and rabbitmq to process tasks, in let's call it APP1. In another host i have APP2, that needs to get results from tasks processed in APP1.

Both APP/hosts have access to rabbitmq, and my first approach was to simple try to share a queue from both APPs without success.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to have the task run on APP1, and when it is done processing the task, post another task to celery. Call this new task `ProcessResults`. The data for this task will be the result of the original task. The worker for this new task would be located on APP2.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same result backend that you used in `APP1`, for example in `APP2`:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult

# set the backend URL that APP1 is using
app = Celery(backend='backend_url')

# The task ID that was queued in APP1
task = AsyncResult('task_id')

# get the task result
task.result
```

You need to store the task ID from `APP1` to be able to get its result in `APP2`, or maybe use a custom task ID if that can help without storing it, but you need to use `Task.apply_async()` to set a custom ID:

```
task.apply_async(args, kwargs, task_id='custom_id')
```